# R How To Perform "Specific" Sampling

Tags: r

I have a dataset that essentially shows baseball players and their positions:

```
*Player       Position*
John Smith       P
Fred Smith      1B
Al Johnson      2B
```

And so on. I would like to randomly sample 9 players at a time from this dataset which one just uses R's sample() function. However, from each sampling I would only like to obtain ONE of each position, i.e., 1P, 1 1B, 1 2B, and so on...

How could I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: not familiar with baseball. is a player capable of playing in multiple positions?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using dplyr, assuming `df` is your dataframe:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    group_by(Position) %>% 
    sample_n(1) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    sample_n(9)
```

Comment: Great solution! I'm wondering if the `ungroup()` and second `sample_n()` are necessary. Mind sharing your logic?

Comment: OP said they only wanted to sample 9 players -- if there are only 9 positions then it is unnecessary (and if there are less than 9 positions it will throw an error).

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given us much information here, but I would group the data by position then take a sample of 1 from each group.  Using *data.table* would be my go-to for this

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)

data[, sample(Player, 1), by = Position]
```

However, in baseball, outfielders are typically all grouped together as one position - `"OF"`. In this case you would have to sample `"OF"` 3 times and all the others just 1.  You could use an `if()` statement in the `size` argument for this scenario.

```
data[, sample(Player, if(Position == "OF") 3 else 1), by = Position]
```